# Change a variable reference after his initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, standards

In the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf%E2%80%8E) you can read that (8.5.3.2 pag.202)

> "A reference cannot be changed to refer to another object after
>   initialization."

but what about the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    int i = 1;
    int &j = i;

    j = 2; // Ok, now i == 2

    int k = 3;

    j = std::ref(k);

    std::cout << "j = " << j << ", i = " << i << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

that produces this output

```
j = 3, i = 3
```

is it realy wrong? is a compiler's "feature" or a C++ language's "feature"? I compiled this code's fragment either on mac (LLVM 5.1) and windows (VS2010).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
 j = std::ref(k);
```

Has exactly the same effect has

```
 j = k
```

That is the reference `std::ref(k)` is implicitly dereferenced before assignement to `k` that is also to `i`. So no wonder the behavior you are seeing. As a proof, just change your code as

```
int i = 1;
int &j = i;
j = 2; // Ok, now i == 2
int k = 3;
j = std::ref(k);
std::cout << "j = " << j << ", i = " << i << std::endl;
k = 5;
std::cout << "j = " << j << ", i = " << i << std::endl;
```

Then the output is

```
j = 3, i = 3
j = 3, i = 3
```

which shows that `j` is not a reference to `k`. Changing `k` doesn't change `j`.

Comment: +1, you're bang on the mark there, I was just about to write up the same answer. Drat you for being so fast and correct ;)

Comment: @fixxxer: There was a remaining typo. I just fixed it.